# Which is more efficient / elegant?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Which method of finding items in one collection based on a property value of each item in another collection is better? Over and above this, is there a better way to do this?

```
List<Thing> results;    

List<Thing> thingList1 = ...;
List<Thing> thingList2 = ...;
```

Method A:

```
results = thingList1.Where(x => thingList2.Any(y => y.Id == x.Id)).ToList();
```

Method B:

```
foreach (Thing thing in thingList1)
{
    results.AddRange(thingList2.Where(x => x.Id == thing.Id).Select(y => thing));
}
```

?

Comment: You should probably be using `Intersect`

Comment: Define "better". Does it work? Does it work fast enough?

Comment: @CodeCaster - I was hoping to get opinions and justifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would choose to make a join:

```
var results = (from item1 in thingList1
               join item2 in thingList2
               on item1.Id equals item2.Id
               select item1).ToList();
```

I think the above approach is more clear in it's intention.

Another option, it would be to use the `Intersect` method:

```
var results = thingList1.Intersect(thingList2);
```

This is more elegant. However, you should pay attention on implementing the interface `IEquatable<Thing>` for your class `Thing`. Otherwise, you can't use it. For further information, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to know is writing a test with real data, however you are doing a where on a list multiple times. Making a Dictionary from the list will give you better performance.

```
Dictionary<int, thing> d = thingList2.ToDictornary(x => x.Id);
foreach (Thing thing in thingList1)
{
    results.Add(d[thing.Id]);
}
```